# Declare the point for incomming arrows on nodes

Tags: pstricks, nodes, node-connections

is there a way to tell the a node, where the arrow shall arrive?

At this example, the Arrow from Node B to A should arrive exactly in the middle of the "D" from "Dies". It should start on top-center of B's text.

Hope this is understandable.

```
\documentclass[11pt, halfparskip,toc=flat,numbers=noendperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman} % deutsche Silbentrennung, Deutsche Ausdrücke

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}


\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(10,5)
    %\psgrid(0,0)(0,0)(10,5)


    \rput[t](5, 5){
        \rnode{A}{
            \parbox[c]{3cm}{
                \centering
                Dies ist Node A
            }
        }
    }

    \rput[t](0, 2.5){
        \rnode{B}{
            \parbox[c]{3.5cm}{
                \centering
                Dies ist der Text\\
                zu Node B
            }
        }
    }

    \rput[t](10,2.5){
        \rnode{C}{
            \parbox[c]{3cm}{
                Mein Name ist C, Node C
            }
        }
    }

    \rput[t](5,0){
        \rnode{D}{
            \parbox[c]{3cm}{
                Ich bin Node D\\
                Ich stehe ganz unten
            }
        }
    }

    \psset{linewidth=.05cm}
    \psset{nodesep=0.1cm}
    \psset{arcangle=45}

    \ncarc{->}{B}{A}
    \ncarc{->}{A}{C}
    \ncarc{->}{C}{D}
    \ncarc{->}{D}{B}

\end{pspicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. `\nccurve` for example allows to specify connection angles and offsets. If less precision were sufficient you could go with a one-liner; since you're looking for exact placement, you need some more code:

```
%calculate offset
\newlength\labellength
\newlength\dlength
\newlength\offset
\settowidth{\labellength}{Dies ist Node A}
\settowidth{\dlength}{D}    
\setlength{\offset}{\dimexpr-.5\labellength+.5\dlength\relax}

%draw curve
\nccurve[angleA=90,angleB=90,offsetB=\offset,ncurvA=.67,ncurvB=.67]{->}{B}{A}
```

The `ncurv` parameters, set to their defaults here, allow you to adjust the curve's shape. A and B, not to be confused with your node names, refer to the start and end node. For more details see the manual linked by @MarcoDaniel; several other options to connect two nodes are presented there as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your current settings it can't be done. The node specifier `\rnode` has an optional argument to specify the refpoint but only once. The specifier is equal to `\rput`.

However the package `pst-node` offers an other way. You can use the new command `\psDefBoxNodes{node name }{text }` whereby the displayed refpoints will be defined:

The example is taken from the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-node):

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(10,6)
\psscalebox{15}{\psDefBoxNodes{Age}{\color{red!50}\sffamily \"Age}}%
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,
fillcolor=blue!30,opacity=0.3](Age:tl)(Age:tr)(Age:br)(Age:bl)%
\psline[linestyle=dashed](Age:Bl)(Age:Br)%
\psdots(Age:tl)(Age:tC)(Age:tr)(Age:Cl)(Age:C)(Age:Cr)%
(Age:Bl)(Age:BC)(Age:Br)(Age:bl)(Age:bC)(Age:br)%
\pcline[arrows=<->,linecolor=blue,arrowscale=1.25](Age:tC)(Age:Br)
\uput[180](Age:tl){tl}\uput[180](Age:Cl){Cl}\uput[180](Age:Bl){Bl}\uput[180](Age:bl){bl}
\uput[90](Age:tC){tC} \uput[0](Age:C){C}
\uput[0](Age:BC){BC} \uput[-90](Age:bC){bC}
\uput[0](Age:tr){tr} \uput[0](Age:Cr){Cr} \uput[0](Age:Br){Br} \uput[0](Age:br){br}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]